# Limit to infinity from a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

Let $R'(t) + \nu R(t) = \nu F(t)$, $F(0)=0$, $R(0)=0$, $f(t) \geq 0$, $F(t) = \int_0^t f(\tau)d\tau$, $F(t) \leq 1$, and $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} F(t) = 1$.

I solved the differential equation and got: $R(t) = F(t) - e^{-\nu t} \int_0^t e^{\nu \tau} f(\tau) d\tau$

How can I prove that $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} R(t) = F(t)$?

I proved that $R(t) \leq F(t)(1 - e^{-\nu t})$ and $R'(t) > 0$. But I guess it is not sufficient, since $R(t)$ could still converge to something less than $F(t)$.

I also proved that $R(t) = \nu e^{-\nu t} \int_0^t e^{\nu \tau} F(\tau) d\tau$.